# Cosmos DB - calculation of final document

Tags: c#, triggers, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Looking for best way to calculate full document in Cosmos DB during insert.

I have two types of documents:
Data documents that I have multiple instances of those.

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":31,
    "city":"New York",
    "Value": ""
}
```

Setting document(s)

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "multiplier":2
}
```

I want to have final document in my container to use a formula like in excel from 2 documents. In this case multiplier x age = value:

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":31,
    "city":"New York"
    "value":62
}
```

I was thinking to have a Data container and Settings container and a trigger in Data container that during insert will use pre-trigger to access setting container and in that trigger have a calculation logic to create a final document in Data container. It sees that cosmos db trigger is limited and I cannot access other container document from trigger.

- If I would put those two documents in the same container, can I use trigger for such calculation?
- If I cannot use trigger, what would be the best use for this scenario and Azure function?
- Any other recommendations of best practice? In SQL server I would just use calculated column or trigger.

Comment: If you think my answer helps you, you could mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First question:

> If I would put those two documents in the same container, can I use trigger for such calculation?

Yes,you can do this calculation.But your two type document must in the same logical partition.The reason of this please refer to the [Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs).

Third question:

> Any other recommendations of best practice? In SQL server I would just use calculated column or trigger.

If you are familiar with Azure Functions,you can use that to do the calculation.
In cosmos DB,if you want to invoke a trigger, you must set a `requestOption` like this:

```
ItemRequestOptions request = new ItemRequestOptions
{
    PreTriggers = new List<string> { "insertValue" }
};
ItemResponse<Users> userResponse = await this.container.CreateItemAsync<Users>(user, null, request);
```

If you use Azure Function,you do not need to set a `requestOption`.

Below is my test trigger code(I insert the setting document already):

```
function insertValue(){

    var context = getContext();
    var container = context.getCollection();

    var request = context.getRequest();
    var multiplier;
    // item to be created in the current operation
    var itemToCreate = request.getBody();
    var name = itemToCreate.name;

    var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.name = "' + name +'" and u.multiplier != null';
    var accept = container.queryDocuments(container.getSelfLink(), filterQuery,
    updateMetadataCallback);
    if(!accept) throw "Unable to find document, abort";

    
    function updateMetadataCallback(err, items, responseOptions) {
        if(err) throw new Error("Error" + err.message);
            if(items.length != 1) throw 'Unable to find  document';

            var userItem = items[0];
            multiplier = userItem.multiplier;
            // update metadata
            if(multiplier){
                itemToCreate["Value"] = multiplier * itemToCreate["age"];
                request.setBody(itemToCreate);
            }
            
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.